# PHP AltoRouter serving only base URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes, altorouter

I am a noobie in PHP, I am setting up a simple Routing using AltoRouter. Below is my index.php and .htaccess file which are at the route folder i.e, /var/www/html/ 
I am using Apache2 for serving the web pages.

index.php

```
<?php
require 'vendor/AltoRouter.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();
// map homepage
$router->map('GET', '/', function () {
    require __DIR__ . '/views/home.php';
});

$router->map('GET|POST', '/login', function () {
    require __DIR__ . '/views/login.php';
});

$router->map('GET', '/signup', function () {
    require __DIR__ . '/views/signup.php';
});

$match = $router->match();

// call closure or throw 404 status
if ($match && is_callable($match['target'])) {
    call_user_func_array($match['target'], $match['params']);
} else {
    // no route was matched
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Problem: 
When I visit localhost, the 'home.php' get served, but when I visit 'localhost/login' or 'localhost/signup', I get 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you should visit `localhost/login.php` .try it please.

Answer (score 2):

Change this code

```
 $router->map('GET', '/', function () {
     require __DIR__ . '/views/home.php'; });

 $router->map('GET|POST', '/login', function () {
     require __DIR__ . '/views/login.php'; });

 $router->map('GET', '/signup', function () {
     require __DIR__ . '/views/signup.php'; });
```

with the following.....

```
$router->map('GET', '/views', '/views/home.php','home');

$router->map('GET', '/views/login', '/views/login.php','login');

$router->map('GET', '/views/signup', '/views/signup.php','signup');
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. Still getting 404

Comment: visit the link https://www.longren.io/basic-routing-in-php-with-altorouter/

Comment: I tried everything from the link before posting question here, not sure where exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that your .htaccess file is being ignored, that's not caused by AltoRouter or PHP.

Depending on which operating system you have, you should search how to activate the .htaccess file on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and you can solve it by adding a base_path to the router . Lets say I have my altoroute project in the directory `http://localhost/myapp/` and my public directory in I have `index.php` file `http://localhost/myapp/public/index.php` the base path should be

```
$router->setBasePath('/myapp/public');
                                   ^----don't but any / here
```

And that's it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253868/altorouter-cant-execute-routes