# Altorouter can't execute routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, altorouter

I am using `Altorouter` in a basic PHP App(No framework) but somehow it's not working. Below are details:

**index.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();

$router->map( 'GET', '/', function() {
    include __DIR__ . 'home.php';
});

print "Done";
```

It prints *Done* and no error in php log.

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I am access it as `http://localhost/home/myapp/

Comment: Should probably be `include __DIR__ . '/home.php';`

Comment: @Phil still, did not work.

Comment: @Phil - yep, and I would even go so far as to say use `require` instead.  The only real benefit of include I have ever found is if you return like an array in the included file. Otherwise require would fail and tell you your missing a slash becase __DIR__ doesn't add the ending slash to path.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it is not working. I now added `$router->setBasePath('/home/myApp/');` but still it is not getting into `map()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured out the issue. The URL I want to access is:

`http://localhost/home/myapp/`

`Altorouter` does not know about root URL so basePath needs to be set. it is done as:

`$router->setBasePath('/home/myapp');`

Do note that there's no trailing `/` should be put in `setBasePath` because we will put that in our `map` function like that:

```
$router->map('GET', '/', 'home.php', 'home');
$match = $router->match();
if ($match) {
    require $match['target'];
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    require '404.html';
}
```

Comment: So the `setBasePath' is causing all these problems?